# Strange 'Empty test suite'. output when running PHPUnit Tests in Docker

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, phpunit, phpstorm

I've set up a `docker-compose` environment with Redis, MySQL, php-fpm, and an Nginx webserver. Here's the relevant parts of `docker-compose.yml`:

```
webserver:
      image: nginx:alpine
      container_name: webserver
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
          - .:/application
          - ./phpdocker/webserver/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      ports:
       - "8082:80"

php-fpm:
      build: phpdocker/php-fpm
      container_name: php-fpm
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - .:/application
        - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
```

And here's the structure of the referenced `php-fpm` build:

```
FROM phpdockerio/php73-fpm:latest
WORKDIR "/application"

# Fix debconf warnings upon build
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Install selected extensions and other stuff
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install  php7.3-mysql php-redis php-xdebug \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

# Install git
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install git \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*
```

You may recognize the structure or defaults; I generated it with [phpdocker](https://phpdocker.io/generator).

My containers are all building nicely, so my next step was to be set up PHPStorm to run the tests from within the php-fpm Docker container. I got the remote interpreter and PHPUnit path set up correctly, ran a basic test, and get this (bizarre) output:

```
docker-compose://[/Users/christian/projects/application/docker-compose.yml]:php-fpm/php /application/src/app/vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration /application/phpunit.xml --filter "/(::testPagesReturnExpectedStatus)( .*)?$/" Tests\Smoke\SmokeTest /application/tests/php/Smoke/SmokeTest.php --teamcity
Starting application__phpstorm_helpers_1 ... 
Recreating php-fpm            ... 
Attaching to php-fpm
php-fpm    | PHPUnit 7.4.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
php-fpm    | 
php-fpm    | Runtime:       PHP 7.3.6-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 with Xdebug 2.7.1
php-fpm    | Configuration: /application/phpunit.xml
php-fpm    | 
php-fpm    | 
php-fpm    | 
php-fpm    | fivefour-php-fpm    | 
php-fpm    | Empty test suite.
php-fpm    | 
php-fpm    | 
php-fpm    | Time: 1.59 seconds, Memory: 6.00 MB
php-fpm    | 
php-fpm    | 
php-fpm    | ERRORS!
php-fpm    | Tests: 9, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
php-fpm exited with code 2
Aborting on container exit...

Process finished with exit code 2
```

There's two things I notice right away: normally, when there are errors in a test, PHPUnit will output those errors. Here, I get nothing. Secondly, I get a message that says 'Empty test suite.', despite the fact that a couple of lines down, it prints 'Tests: 9, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1`, which doesn't seem like an empty test suite to me.

In short, I've absolutely no idea what's going on or even how to troubleshoot it! If anyone has some insight, I would great appreciate it.

Comment: The first thing to check here is if the output is any different when you run the same command (`php /application/src/app/vendor/bin/phpunit blah-blah`) manually with `docker-compose run` (or `docker-compose exec`, depending on how you configured your remote interpreter).

Comment: That's a good question. I tried the same command and got the same output, but on a hunch I removed that `--teamcity` argument that PHPUnit adds. Finally, I can see my error! But, it doesn't seem practical to, whenever my tests fail, re-run the tests from the command line and remove that argument to see the error output.

Comment: Is the `Empty test suite` warning still there without the `--teamcity` argument? From what I can see, errors still should be printed out even with the argument, so I suppose the issue is caused by something else: http://prntscr.com/o2tnnt

Comment: Empty test-suite in Phpunit means that no tests are found. That are either no test files (classes) at all or those found do not contain any test methods. Check all files are available inside the Docker container if you execute the files there. Phpstorm remote interpreter does temporarily move files there-in (or uses mapping), it is pretty limited, e.g. you can't see it working with non-project files, like scratch files.

Answer (score 2):

I 'solved' this by setting up my docker image to allow SSH access, then using PHPStorm's SSH remote interpreter instead of the docker remote interpreter. I'm hesitant to accept my solution as the real answer, since it's more of a workaround, but I'll leave it here for posterity / future Googlers.